# How to log in to Amway.com using Webclient

Tags: c#, html, post, webclient

Can anyone explain to me using code how can i log on to Amway.com using WEbClient. This is uptill now what i came up with. Please provide suggestions or links to other materials that i can study and get through with. Thanks in advance.

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                WebHeaderCollection headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
                headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
                headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0");
                client.Headers = headers;
                var values = new NameValueCollection
                {
                    { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$UserName", "username" },
                    { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$Password", "password" },
                };
                byte[] result = client.UploadValues("https://www.amway.in/Users/Login.aspx", "POST", values);
                string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
            }


public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public CookieAwareWebClient()
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
            request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
            return request;
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I suggest removing your user id and password?

Comment: It will still appear in the revision history. I suggest changing your password everywhere you used this one.

Comment: I removed, but mistake is a mistake. OP has to change the password if that's the original password :(
.

Comment: If you install [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) you can log all http requests and responses which you have to mimick in your c# code.

Comment: It was a dummy password BTW.

Comment: I installed fiddler and added headers likewise but getting no results